How to combine parametric equations for three coordinates into one equation?
I am given a set of parametric equations:
$$ x = x_o \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{2t}{s} \right)$$
$$ y = y_o \cdot \exp\left(\frac{t}{s} \right)$$
$$ z = z_o \cdot \exp\left(\frac{t}{s} \right), $$
where $x_o, y_o, z_o$ are constants and $t, s$ are parameters. I would ideally like an equation in the form $f(x, x_o, y, y_o, z, z_o, s) = 0$ and the parameter $t$ to disappear. That way I can put the equation into a graphing calculator (e.g. Desmos) and get all the curves this produces by changing only one parameter $s$. Is this even possible? I can express $t$ from each equation, but I am unsure what to do next...
$$t = \ln\left( \sqrt{\left(\frac{x_o}{x}\right)^s}\right)$$
$$t = s \cdot \ln\left( \frac{y}{y_o}\right)$$
$$t = s \cdot \ln\left( \frac{z}{z_o}\right)$$

These particular equations are fairly simple, in that they depend on only ratios of the variables: $X=x/x_0$, $Y=y/y_0$, $Z=z/z_0$, and $T=t/s$.  And then you just have $Y=Z=e^{T}$ and $X=1/Y^2$.  So while you can do what you’re asking, the parametrized curves are essentially all the same: $(X,Y,Z)=(1/\alpha^2, \alpha, \alpha)$, where $\alpha=e^T$ can take any positive value.
